# Python + ElasticSearch: Mapper Parsing Exceptions for join field

Tags: python, elasticsearch, exception, indexing, mapping

I'm using ElasticSearch 8.3.2 to store some data I have. The data consists of metabolites and several "studies" for each metabolite, with each study in turn containing concentration values. I am also using the [Python ElasticSearch client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.6.0/)  to communicate with the backend, which works fine.
To associate metabolites with studies, I was considering using a join field as described [here](https://medium.com/swlh/parent-and-child-joins-with-elasticsearch-7-381f6cca73fe).

I have defined this index mapping:

```
INDEXMAPPING_MET = {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {"type": "keyword"},
            "entry_type": {"type": "text"},
            "pc_relation": {
                "type": "join",
                "relations": {
                    "metabolite": "study"
                }
            },
            "concentration": {
                "type": "nested",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`pc_relation` is the join field here, with metabolites being the parent documents of each study document.
I can create metabolite entries (the parent documents) just fine using the Python client, for example

```py
self.client.index(index="metabolitesv2", id=metabolite, body=json.dumps({
                #[... some other fields here]
                "pc_relation": {
                    "name": "metabolite",
                },
            }))
```

However, once I try adding child documents, I get a `mapping_parser_exception`. Notably, I only get this exception when trying to add the `pc_relation` field, any other fields work just fine and I can create documents if I omit the join field. Here is an example for a study document I am trying to create (on the same index):

```py
self.client.index(index="metabolitesv2", id=study, body=json.dumps({
                #[... some other fields here]
                "pc_relation": {
                    "name": "study",
                    "parent": metabolite_id
                },
            }))
```

At first I thought there might be some typing issues, but casting everything to a string sadly does not change the outcome. I would really appreciate any help with regards to where the error could be as I am not really sure what the issue is - From what I can tell from the official ES documentation and other Python+ES projects I am not really doing anything differently.

**Tried**: Creating an index with a join field, creating a parent document, creating a child document with a join relation to the parent.
**Expectation**: Documents get created and can be queried using `has_child` or `has_parent` tags.
**Result**: MappingParserException when trying to create the child document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

You need to [provide a routing value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) at indexing time for the child document.

> The routing value is mandatory because parent and child documents must be indexed on the same shard

By default the routing value of a document is its `_id`, so in practice you need to provide the `_id` of the parent document when indexing the child.

## Solution

```py
self.client.index(index="metabolitesv2", id=study, routing=metabolite, body=json.dumps({
    #[... some other fields here]
    "pc_relation": {
        "name": "study",
        "parent": metabolite_id
    },
}))
```

## To reproduce

```json
PUT 75224800
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 4
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "pc_relation": {
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "metabolite": "study"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT 75224800/_doc/1
{
  "id": "1",
  "pc_relation": "metabolite"
}

# No routing Id this is going to fail
PUT 75224800/_doc/2
{
  "id": 2,
  "pc_relation":{
    "name": "study",
    "parent": "1"
  }
}

PUT 75224800/_doc/3
{
  "id": "3",
  "pc_relation": "metabolite"
}

PUT 75224800/_doc/4?routing=3
{
  "id": 2,
  "pc_relation":{
    "name": "study",
    "parent": "3"
  }
}
```